# How to parallelize terraform commands for each directory of my list?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, terraform

Currently, I'm grabbing a string list of directories and individually navigating to each of these - then executing my terraform operations. This takes a long time to run since it goes through each directory after the other.

Since I cannot use "parallel" within a script block, is there a workaround to navigate (and execute) to all of my directories simultaneously?

```
   pipeline {
        agent {
            docker { 
                image 'hashicorp/terraform:latest' 
                args '--entrypoint="" --platform linux/amd64 -d'
            }
        }             
      stages {
        stage('Example') {
          steps {
            script {
                def directories = getDirectories("$WORKSPACE/modules/")
                directories.each{ f ->
                    dir ("${f.name}") {
                        sh ('terraform init')
                        sh ('terraform validate')
                    }    
                }    
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    @NonCPS
    def getDirectories(path) {
        def dir = new File(path)
        def dirs = []
        dir.traverse(type: groovy.io.FileType.DIRECTORIES, maxDepth: 0) { d ->
            dirs.add(d) 
        }
        return dirs
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/#parallel-stages

the idea that `parallel` jenkins step could accept a map of `[name, {steps}]`

```
   pipeline {
        agent {
            docker { 
                image 'hashicorp/terraform:latest' 
                args '--entrypoint="" --platform linux/amd64 -d'
            }
        }             
      stages {
        stage('Example') {
          steps {
            script {
                def directories = getDirectories("$WORKSPACE/modules/")
                parallel directories.collectEntries{ f ->
                    [f.name, {
                        dir("$f") {
                            sh ('terraform init')
                            sh ('terraform validate')
                        }
                    }]
                }   
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

PS: not sure if collectEntries is CPS-safe

---

UPD: there are multiple answers for your question over internet...

https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3073/how-to-properly-achieve-dynamic-parallel-action-with-a-declarative-pipeline